# How do I force eof on stdin?

Tags: c++, stdin, eof

For a C++ application, how can I programmatically force an end of file (EOF) on stdin?

Comment: How do you mean 'force EOF on stdin'?  You could close stdin (or cin).  You could have your loop terminate unilaterally.  You could seek to the end of the file (but that won't help with a terminal or pipe as input).  You might be able to force the issue with `freopen()`; reassign standard input to read from /dev/null or NUL:.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, you cannot. As long as you can read data from stdin, EOF hasn't been reached, and in fact you can never reach it. You can close the `stdin` itself, however. To close it, do this:

```
fclose(stdin);
```

After this, you cannot read data from `stdin`.

Answer (score 17):

If you're at a terminal in a Unix-like system, hit `Ctrl-D`.  In Windows, `Ctrl-Z`.

Edit: Having seen the desire to do this "programmatically," I suggest trying `fclose(stdin)`.  If somehow that's not good enough, a crazier idea might be to use `std::cin.rdbuf()` to set the stream to refer to something other than the true stdin, and then do what you want to that stream.  But this starts to smell bad, like you are fighting against the computer, so I'd like to know more about what the real goal is.

Comment: But this is from within a C++ application, so does sending Ctrl-D work?

Comment: Oh I see "programmatically" now.  Maybe you can describe in more detail what you are trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to solve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4701282/how-to-figure-out-why-ssh-session-does-not-exit-sometimes

Comment: Aha!  Then the real solution is to use `libssh` or `libssh2`, rather than calling `popen()` from C only to invoke `ssh(1)` which itself is another C program.  Cut out the middlemen!

Comment: @JohnZwinck, but Ctrl-Z doesn't work for me, it gives me a `^Z`, what's wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice little function available for every stream created especially for this.

It's syntax is something like:

```
      stream.setstate(stream.flags)
```

So in your code you can have a simple condition that triggers something like:

```
      std::cin.setstate(std::cin.eofbit);
```

The documentation for this is pretty sparse but there's some on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/setstate) and [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/setstate/).